# Finding the address of /bin/bash for buffer overflow attack

Tags: bash, buffer-overflow

I am trying out ret-to-libc attacks and use the following piece of code to get the address of environment variable /bin/bash

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{

  printf("bash address: 0x%lx\n", getenv("SHELL"));
 return 0;
}
```

when i use gdb's x command to check if the address returned by this code is correct it shows up correctly the first time.But when some other program is executed this address changes automatically.What should i do to keep this environment variable's address constant? I am using this address for buffer overflow, but since it keeps changing with every run, the attack is never successful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply put, you can't. There's nothing that would guarantee a fixed address for an environment variable.

Comment: Wtf is the "environment variable `/bin/bash`"?

Comment: Ah, I see. But using some unknown `$SHELL` *can't* be better than using your own constant `"/bin/sh"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the ASLR for the address to not change.

```
echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```